# AWS Glue Job - Convert CSV to Parquet

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, parquet, aws-glue

I am trying to convert about 1.5 GB of GZIPPED CSV into Parquet using AWS Glue. The script below is an autogenerated Glue job to accomplish that task. It seems to take a very long time (I've waited hours for 10 DPUs and never seen it end or produce any output data)

I'm wondering if anyone has any experience converting 1.5 GB + GZIPPED CSV into Parquet - is there a better way to accomplish this conversion?

I have TB's of data to convert. It is concerning that it seems to take so long to convert GBs.

My Glue Job Logs have thousands of entries like:

```
18/03/02 20:20:20 DEBUG Client: 
client token: N/A
diagnostics: N/A
ApplicationMaster host: 172.31.58.225
ApplicationMaster RPC port: 0
queue: default
start time: 1520020335454
final status: UNDEFINED
tracking URL: http://ip-172-31-51-199.ec2.internal:20888/proxy/application_1520020149832_0001/
user: root
```

AWS Autogenerated Glue Job Code:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)
## @type: DataSource
## @args: [database = "test_datalake_db", table_name = "events2_2017_test", transformation_ctx = "datasource0"]
## @return: datasource0
## @inputs: []
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "test_datalake_db", table_name = "events2_2017_test", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")
## @type: ApplyMapping
## @args: [mapping = [("sys_vortex_id", "string", "sys_vortex_id", "string"), ("sys_app_id", "string", "sys_app_id", "string"), ("sys_pq_id", "string", "sys_pq_id", "string"), ("sys_ip_address", "string", "sys_ip_address", "string"), ("sys_submitted_at", "string", "sys_submitted_at", "string"), ("sys_received_at", "string", "sys_received_at", "string"), ("device_id_type", "string", "device_id_type", "string"), ("device_id", "string", "device_id", "string"), ("timezone", "string", "timezone", "string"), ("online", "string", "online", "string"), ("app_version", "string", "app_version", "string"), ("device_days", "string", "device_days", "string"), ("device_sessions", "string", "device_sessions", "string"), ("event_id", "string", "event_id", "string"), ("event_at", "string", "event_at", "string"), ("event_date", "string", "event_date", "string"), ("int1", "string", "int1", "string")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1"]
## @return: applymapping1
## @inputs: [frame = datasource0]
applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = datasource0, mappings = [("sys_vortex_id", "string", "sys_vortex_id", "string"), ("sys_app_id", "string", "sys_app_id", "string"), ("sys_pq_id", "string", "sys_pq_id", "string"), ("sys_ip_address", "string", "sys_ip_address", "string"), ("sys_submitted_at", "string", "sys_submitted_at", "string"), ("sys_received_at", "string", "sys_received_at", "string"), ("device_id_type", "string", "device_id_type", "string"), ("device_id", "string", "device_id", "string"), ("timezone", "string", "timezone", "string"), ("online", "string", "online", "string"), ("app_version", "string", "app_version", "string"), ("device_days", "string", "device_days", "string"), ("device_sessions", "string", "device_sessions", "string"), ("event_id", "string", "event_id", "string"), ("event_at", "string", "event_at", "string"), ("event_date", "string", "event_date", "string"), ("int1", "string", "int1", "string")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")
## @type: ResolveChoice
## @args: [choice = "make_struct", transformation_ctx = "resolvechoice2"]
## @return: resolvechoice2
## @inputs: [frame = applymapping1]
resolvechoice2 = ResolveChoice.apply(frame = applymapping1, choice = "make_struct", transformation_ctx = "resolvechoice2")
## @type: DropNullFields
## @args: [transformation_ctx = "dropnullfields3"]
## @return: dropnullfields3
## @inputs: [frame = resolvechoice2]
dropnullfields3 = DropNullFields.apply(frame = resolvechoice2, transformation_ctx = "dropnullfields3")
## @type: DataSink
## @args: [connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": "s3://devops-redshift*****/prd/parquet"}, format = "parquet", transformation_ctx = "datasink4"]
## @return: datasink4
## @inputs: [frame = dropnullfields3]
datasink4 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = dropnullfields3, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": "s3://devops-redshift*****/prd/parquet"}, format = "parquet", transformation_ctx = "datasink4")
job.commit()
```

Comment: have you tried to convert much smaller file? How long does it take?

Comment: one more: GZIPPED format is not splittable. Most probably only one executor is working. Try to setup development endpoint and share what is happennig

Comment: Completed in 4.5 hours. I think you must be onto something with the non-splittable gziped files.

Comment: Try a test on your desktop with spark in local mode. That should be your reference time for a single machine & real filesystem. As natalia notes, you can't split .gz files, so there's no parallelism

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I've recently figured out that Spark DataFrames - versus Glue's DynamicFrames - are the significantly faster way to go.

```
# boiler plate, generated code
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

# some job-specific variables
compression_type = 'snappy' # 'snappy', 'gzip', or 'none'
source_path = 's3://source-bucket/part1=x/part2=y/'
destination_path = 's3://destination-bucket/part1=x/part2=y/'

# CSV to Parquet conversion
df = spark.read.option('delimiter','|').option('header','true').csv(source_path)
df.write.mode("overwrite").format('parquet').option('compression', compression_type).save(destination_path )
job.commit()
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot soon and mark as answer if it works. Thanks.

Comment: @Drew Well don't leave us hanging. Did it work...?

Comment: @gbeaven Sorry I can't say. We ended up writing our own tool versus using Glue for this one.